# Regex for capturing smallest group

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to capture an ID for a PDF **Page** object that looks like this :

```
4 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page /
...
>>
endobj
```

The ID is this '**ID** 0 obj'. The problem is that my file has multiple objects and so the following pattern captures from the first object declaration to the first instance of a **Page** object :

```
preg_match_all("/([0-9]+) 0 obj.+?\/Page[ \n]*?\//s", $input_lines, output_array);
```

Here is a sample of my file if you want to try it out, you will see that are multiple objects that include the word 'Page' :

```
%PDF-1.3
%¦¦¦¦

1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog /AcroForm << /Fields [12 0 R 13 0 R] /NeedAppearances false  /SigFlags 3 /Version /1.7 /Pages 3 0 R /Names << >> /ViewerPreferences << /Direction /L2R >> /PageLayout /SinglePage /PageMode /UseNone /OpenAction [0 0 R /FitH null] /DR << /Font << /F1 14 0 R >> >> /DA (/F1 0 Tf 0 g) /Q 0 >> /Perms << /DocMDP 11 0 R >>
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R
>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Outlines
/Count 0
>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Count 2
/Kids [ 4 0 R 6 0 R ]
>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 3 0 R
/Resources <<
/Font <<
/F1 9 0 R
>>
/ProcSet 8 0 R
>>
/MediaBox [0 0 612.0000 792.0000]
/Contents 5 0 R
>>
endobj

5 0 obj
<< /Length 1074 >>
stream
2 J
BT
0 0 0 rg
/F1 0027 Tf
57.3750 722.2800 Td
( A Simple PDF File ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 0010 Tf
```

What should I change to not make it greedy ?

**EDIT :** Clarifications

- I forgot to mention that I need to capture all of the **Page** object IDs.
- As some people told me to use more specific regex, I have to say that this is not a formal example of how objects are build and this one is also possible. You can see that the spaces are not mendatory and that there can be multiple tags before the Page '/Type /Page' tag.

Example :

```
4 0 obj
<< /UselessTag/Type/Page/
...
>>
endobj
```

- There are tags called **Pages**, **PageLayout**, **SiglePage** and I don't want to capture them.

Comment: Are after 1, 2 or 3 matches here? There are several "records" with `/Pages`.

Comment: I am not sure now: what is the marker string for a Page entry? `/Pages`, `/Page` or both? Can we assume that a *whole word `Page` is a marker*? Or is it `/Page` or `Page/`?

Comment: I edited my question to clarify everything that was asked in the comments.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. The marker is `/Type` followed by 0+ spaces, then `/Page` followed with whitespace.

Comment: Yes, and there can be line breaks after **/Type** haha. This regex is exhausting me...

Comment: It is OK, see my answer. Its performance might be improved, let know via a comment if it is too slow for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~^(\d+) 0 obj(?:(?!^\d+ 0 obj$).)*?\/Type\s*\/Page\s.*?endobj$~sm'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SONnlb/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a line anchor (as `m` modifier makes `^` match start of a line and not of a whole string)
- `(\d+) 0 obj` - 1 or more digits (captured into Group 1), then space, `0`, space and an `obj` substring
- `(?:(?!^\d+ 0 obj$).)*?` - a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat/37343088#37343088) that matches any char (`.`) that does not start a `^\d+ 0 obj$` pattern, as few times as possible
- `\/Type\s*\/Page\s` - `/Type`, 0+ whitespaces (replace `\s` with `\h` to only match horizontal whitespace), `/Page` and then a whitespace
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first occurrence of
- `endobj` - `endobj` followed with...
- `$` - the end of line position.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't work with regular expressions on PDF. There are several conditions, where this approach will fail.

1. The page object is inside an object stream (and therefor packed, most probably by a Deflate algorithm) (This is allowed with PDF version 1.5 and up)
2. Incremental updates inside the PDF document can lead to double hits on the same page
3. The marker /Page is not inside the dictionary, which you want to match, but inside an indirect object (never seen, but theoretically possible). E.g you have:

> ```
> 5 0 obj
> << /Type 6 0 R ....>>
> endobj     
> 6 0 obj
> /Page
> endobj
> ```

Note: You also cannot expect, that each page is written in the order inside the pdf document, as you see it in the viewer.

But if you really must do it in that way, i would first match the pdf object with

> /([0-9]+) 0 obj(.+?)endobj/

and would search in the second matched string for

> //Type\s*\Page[\s>]/

The optional matching for > at the end is important, because you need to be able to match also "/Type/Page>>", where /Type/Page is the last entry in the pdf dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can put in an ungreedy Questionmark to a specific Quantifier:

Example:

```
 \(.*\)
```

Matches:

test **(test)test(test)test(test)** test

Example:

```
 \(.*?\)
```

Matches:

test **(test)** test(test)test(test)test

Comment: You are wrong, `U` modifier does not make a regex ungreedy. It *swaps* greediness of the quantifiers used in the pattern.

Comment: If you test your solution, you  will see [it matches too much](https://regex101.com/r/Bxld3n/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try more specific regex so it does not match unneeded part of text.

```
preg_match_all("/([0-9]+?) 0 obj\n\<\<\n\/Type\s\/Page[ \n]*?\//s", $input_lines, output_array);
```

Proof: https://regex101.com/r/HjyQpS/1

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(\d+) 0 obj[^>]+/Page$
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/wc8mBk/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression:

```
/\d+\s0\sobj.+endobj/smU
```

Note that the modifier `U` makes the match non-greedy. See the matching example here:https://www.tinywebhut.com/regex/8